# Solution to $a^k \equiv b \pmod c$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I was trying to find the smallest solution for $k$ to the following equation.
$ a^k = b\bmod c$. The problem is, the $'k'$ I get may not be the smallest. To find the smallest such $k$, I need to compute $O_c(a)$. I was only able to find resources that say that $O_c(a)|\phi(c)\ or \ \lambda(c)$ when $a$ and $c$ are coprime. Is there any such relation when $a$ and $c$ are non-coprime?

Comment: when $a$ and $c$ are not coprime, there might not be a solution to $a^k\equiv b\pmod c$

Comment: Yes that is true, but I know how to compute whether such a solution exists or not and one value of k. I don't know how to get the smallest value of k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulo prime powers $p^m$, the problem becomes much easier: either $p$ divides $a$, in which case we're just looking at the powers of $p$ dividing $a$ and $b$, or else $p$ doesn't divide $a$, in which case your procedure using the order works. Indeed, modulo prime powers, it's pretty easy to find not just a particular $k$ but actually all positive integers $k$ that satisfy $a^k\equiv b\pmod{p^m}$ (it will consist either of a finite set or a full arithmetic progression).

Therefore: factor $c$ into its prime power factors, find the corresponding set of positive integers $k$ for each prime power factor, and then find the smallest integer $k$ that is in the intersection of all those sets. This last task boils down to a Chinese remainder theorem calculation, due to the structure of the individual sets.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, But If only you could eloborate on what to do when p divides a, that would help me a lot. I'm only in high school, so this isn't trivial for me.

Comment: To solve $a^k\equiv b\pmod{p^m}$ when $p$ divides $a$: let $x\ge1$ be the power of $p$ dividing $a$ (that is, $a=p^x c$ with $p\nmid c$) and let $y\ge0$ be the power of $p$ dividing $b$. Check that if $y\ge m$, then $k$ is a solution if and only if $kx\ge m$, while if $y<m$, then $k$ can only be a solution if $kx=y$ (it's not automatically a solution, but there's only one value to check).

Answer (score 0):

Solving $a^k \equiv b \:(\mathrm{mod}\:n)$ is called the [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) (see article for list of special case algorithms), and modular exponentiation for groups whose minimum order is high* is a classic example of a [one-way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function). Such functions are the foundation of modern cryptography, such as can be seen in [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) and the [RSA asymmetric encryption scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).

If the discrete logarithm problem can be solved in polynomial time — which it can be with sufficient quantum computational power; see [Shor's algorithm](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37018/using-shors-algorithm-to-solve-the-discrete-logarithm-problem) — then such schemes are not secure.

With classical computation, the only known feasible way to solve the problem in all cases is to enumerate $a^k \mathrm{mod}\: n$ for all $k$ between 1 and $n$.

---

*particularly when the modulus $n$ is a large prime (though I understand you're not interested in that), so that $n$ is near minimal for a given level of security, and a generator $g$ of the group exists, whence we like to choose $a=g$ for maximal security.